# Device to provide wan over wifi

Tags: router, access-point

I did some digging around that topic, but can't really find straight forward answer for this question. My background: I'm going to spend some time in hotel. I would like to hook up to hotel's wi fi with some kind of device (so WAN over wi fi) and create separate network just for myself in the room, available over wi fi as well.

Is there any device which could do this? I've read about bridges and access points, however I'm still not sure if they will do the trick.

Comment: [Here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8218/router-that-can-connect-to-a-wifi-network-and-create-a-new-wifi-network) is a similar question that may be helpful

Comment: @Alpha3031 correct me if I'm wrong. Network extender will need cable in order to get WAN, to create what I want I need wifi as wan?

Comment: No, network extenders will work fine. WiFi-as-WAN devices do the same thing, but usually also happen to have a full featured router attached, with all the other WAN bits as well.